# after infinitely many row operations, the solution space stays the same?

Tags: linear-algebra, set-theory

Assume there is an $I\times J$ matrix $A$ with infinitely many rows ($I$ is an infinite set) and each row vector has finite support.

Assume we are doing elementary row operations on the row vectors of $A$ so that row $i$ stays fixed after finitely many changes on it.

Then after all the row operations (possibly infinitely many as each row indexed by $I$ gets some change), will the solution space stay the same as that of $Ax=0$?

I am trying to prove it by transfinite induction on $|I|$. And it seems true when $|I|$ is a successor cardinal. Is it true when $|I|$ is a limit cardinal?

Comment: I'm curious as to how you reached the conclusion that this is true when $|I|$ is a successor cardinal

Comment: My feeling is that assuming after the first $|I|$ rows are settled, the solution space stays the same. Then when we work on the $|I|+1$ rows, we need only extra finitely many operations, which is reversible.

Answer (score 2):

This seems not to be the case. For example, if we start with the infinite identity matrix (taking $I = \Bbb N$), we could swap rows $i$ and $i + 1$ for $i = 0,1,2,3,\dots$ to end up with the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{0&1&0&\cdots\\
&0&1&0&\cdots\\
&&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots}.
$$
The initial matrix has only the trivial solution to $Ax = 0$, but the final result has the solution $x = (1,0,0,\dots)$.

Note that no changes occur to the $i$th row after the $i$th row operation.

Comment: While the $(1,0,0,...)$ is still a row of the matrix (thought we are never able to write it down) and it requires $x_1=0$？

Comment: @Ryan Yes, the zeroeth row will be $(0,1,0,0,\dots)$ after switching rows $0$ and $1$, and is not changed after that.

Comment: @Connor $(1,0,0,\dots)$ is **not** a row of the final result. There is no $i \in \Bbb N$ such that the $i$th row of the result is $(1,0,0,\dots)$.

Comment: @RyanK: What might this slightly different phrasing be? It seems to me that the question meant just what this answer adresses, and I don't see what it could be slightly tweaked to mean that would be true. Perhaps you have something in mind like demanding not that the actual rows eventually stop changing but that the original rows eventually stop wandering – but elementary row operations can do more than move rows somewhere else unchanged – the original rows may no longer exist, so the only thing that we can require to eventually stay unchanged are the actual rows.